# how to compile source file using ant

Tags: java, ant

I am very new in `ant` programming, i have made a `build.xml` which only execute the compiled file. but what i want to learn now is " it should automatically build the `.java` file and move it to the `target` folder.

currently i am compiling java file from eclipse & moving it to target folder & then running with `ant`.

I have a folder structure like

```
 Myproject
     source
         Helloworld.java
     target
     lib
     build.xml
```

in my build.xml i have below code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<project name="Hello World Project" default="info">
   <path id="master-classpath"> <fileset dir="lib"> <include name="*.jar"/> </fileset> </path> 
   <target name="info"> 
  <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes">
      <classpath>  
     <pathelement location="target"/>   
    </classpath> 
  <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>

    <test name="Helloworld"  haltonfailure="no" outfile="result"> 
      <formatter type="plain"/>
      <formatter type="xml"/> 
    </test> 
  </junit>
</target>
</project>
```

Comment: Have you discovered the `javac` task in ant yet?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen No not yet

Comment: Have a look at it - you might find it usable for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `javac` ant task somewhat like this:

```
<target name="build" description="Compile main source tree java files">
    <mkdir dir="target"/>
    <javac destdir="target" source="1.6" target="1.6" debug="true"
           deprecation="false" optimize="false" failonerror="true">
        <src path="src"/>
        <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>
```

you need to put all the dependency jars in  the `master-classpath`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you edit your answer in-terms of my folder name as i specified above ?  `${}` this type of symbol are confusing for me

Comment: just edited. please see. I am assuming that you are using JDK 6 and kept the class version as 1.6. change it as per your jdk.

Comment: Let you know once i tested & understood it , probably after half and hour